# how to get image URL form firebase storage to firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

i am trying to upload the image to firebase and get the URL in firestore. It does upload the image but it does not get the URL to Firestore.

this is how i get the image.

```
Future getImage1() async {
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    var firstImage = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
        source: ImageSource.gallery, imageQuality: 65);
    setState(() {
      _image1 = firstImage;
    });
  }
```

this is how i upload and get the url.

```
  uploadPic() async {
    Reference ref = storage.ref().child("image1" + DateTime.now().toString());
    UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(_image1);
    uploadTask.then((res) {
      String url = res.ref.getDownloadURL().toString();
      imageUrl1 = url;
      return url;
    });
  }
```

this is how i get the link in firestore

```
"image 1 Url":(_image1 != null) ? await uploadPic() : null,
```

Comment: What are you expecting to see in Firestore?  There's no code here that writes any documents there.  Firebase Storage is a completely different product than Firestore.

Comment: You will have to make two network calls. One to upload the image to the storage, and then to store the image URL to firestore collection. you already have the uploading out of the way. you have to now add to firestore collection or document.

Comment: I updated the question take a look. @DougStevenson

Comment: I need your **HELP** @PeterHaddad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getDownloadURL is a Future, so how about you try it like this:

```
Future<String> uploadPic() async {
    Reference ref = storage.ref().child("image1" + DateTime.now().toString());
    UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(_image1);
    String url;
    await uploadTask.whenComplete(() {
      res.ref.getDownloadURL().then((fileUrl){
      url = fileUrl as String;
      });
    });
    return url;
  }
```

Comment: it doesn't help @FarhanSyah

Comment: @MtKhalifa what is your error? Did you check the url value using print first? Try print(url) and print(fileUrl) before the return statement. If the value exist, that means, the error is in someplace else. I have tried above code, and I can get the result

Comment: the part with **onComplete** gives the following error. the getter 'onComplete' isn't defined for the type 'uploadTask'.

Comment: Change to StorageUploadTask, reference also change to StorageReference. Please note that I am using firebase_storage: ^4.0.1

Comment: well, i make it work by down grading the version of Firebase_Storage

Comment: I didn't notice the version difference at first.  let me try upgrading my package to version 5 and try. I'll let you know.

Comment: @MtKhalifa  i can make it work in v5.0.1, by using whenComplete method, and registering the function as callback . I have updated the answer